# NSMutableDictionary random EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Any idea why code below throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS randomly (not always). Sometime when `userid` is same but we yet to figure out more cases. I understand that `setObject:o` is unnecessary when object already exists in the dictionary, but even if used, it should not have crashed.

mDict is `NSMutableDictionary`

```
-(void) addUser:(NSString *)userid address:(NSString *)address {
    if(nil == userid || nil == address) return;

    User *o = [mDict objectForKey:userid];
    if(!o)
       o = [User new];

    o.userid = userid;
    o.address = address;

    [mDict setObject:o forKey:o.userid];
}
```

Comment: Are `userid` and `address` always non-`nil`?  That's one reason I can think of an exception.  You need to see what is happening within the debugger.

Comment: all are surely not-nil, updating code

Comment: Then more detail is required.

Comment: what kind of details? I have given the full code

Comment: What does the exception say?  Has it raised an exception within the debugger?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, I mentioned that in my post.

Comment: On which line? Did you add an exception breakpoint? Multiple threads?

Comment: Maybe mDict is "assign" in the property declaration?

Comment: probably a race condition with accessing NSMutableDictionary. You should wrap the setter process in @synchronize or with a dispatch queue  or a mutex lock of some sort and see if it solves it, assuming you've checked everything else